# Constructing a replicating portfolio of a long-only strategy using long-short factors

Tags: returns, regression, factor-models, capm, replication

Lets say I want to estimate a replicating portfolio by doing a linear regression between the returns of a long-only portfolio and several long-short factors like **Fama-French 5-factor** or **Betting Against Beta** (CAPM framework).

I discover that I can replicate and explain about 60% of the variance in my **long-only portfolio** ($R^2$ of ~0.6) with 3 significant coefficients to some of the **long-short factors** mentioned above. Does this comparison even make sense when replicating a long-only strategy with multiple long-short strategies?